# Show data output depending on which action button pressed

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am creating a shiny app that will allow users to upload data and show the contents on the main panel. There are two action buttons, one to show some example data and the other action button to show the contents of the uploaded data file. if the user hasn't uploaded any data file then clicking on the second action button should return a message saying 'please upload data first'. I'm struggling to implement this second action button, so any help is greatly appreciated.

I have tried using `reactiveVal ()` but it's not working with the second action button. I think i need to somehow save the uploaded data set into a object that can be retrieved by the second action button.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)


options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2) 

recommendation <- tibble(Account = c("Axis", "HSBC", "SBI", "ICICI", "Bandhan Bank", "Axis", "HSBC", "SBI", "ICICI", "Bandhan Bank"),
                             Product = c("Bank", "FBB", "FBB", "FBB","FBB","SIMO", "SIMO", "SIMO", "SIMO", "SIMO"),
                             Region = c("North", "South", "East", "West", "West", "North", "South", "East", "West", "West"),
                             Revenue = c(2000, 30000, 1000, 1000, 200, 200, 300, 100, 100, 200))


ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Example"),


  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      fileInput("Upload", "Upload your own Data"),

      actionButton("Example", "Show Example Data instead"),
      actionButton("data", "Show New data")


    ),

    mainPanel(

      column(DT::dataTableOutput('showdata'), width = 12),

    )
  )
)

# Server Logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  my_data <- reactiveVal()

  observeEvent(input$Upload, {
    tmp <- read.csv(input$Upload$datapath)
    my_data(tmp)
  })

  observeEvent(input$Example, {
    my_data(recommendation)

  })

  observeEvent(input$data, {
    my_data()

  })

  output$showdata = renderDT(my_data(), rownames = FALSE, class = "display nowrap compact", filter = "top",
                           options = list(
                             scrollX = TRUE,
                             scrollY = TRUE,
                             autoWidth = FALSE))

}



# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Clicking on 'show new data' action button, should show the data that was just uploaded. However, if there isn't any uploaded data then a message should prompt the user to upload a data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the way you are using `reactiveVal` when the button is pressed returns an empty value (`my_data()` returns nothing). Also, there is no need of the first `observeEvent` in your server code, as this will update `my_data` only when a file is uploaded, not when the button is pressed.
My way of doing this would be checking if there is a file uploaded when pressing the show new data, and if there is one, show it. If not, prompt a modal dialog to inform the user to upload a file first. Something like this (writing only the server function, as the rest is unchanged):

```
# Server Logic
server <- function(input, output) {

  my_data <- reactiveVal()

  ## Not need of this, this will be done when pressing the show data button
  # observeEvent(input$Upload, {
  #   tmp <- read.csv(input$Upload$datapath)
  #   my_data(tmp)
  # })

  # Observer to update my_data when example button is pressed
  observeEvent(input$Example, {
    my_data(recommendation)
  })

  # Observer to update my_data when data button is pressed, checking if there
  # is a file uploaded
  observeEvent(input$data, {

    # check if we have a data uploaded
    if (is.null(input$Upload)) {
      # if there is no data uploaded, reset my_data, and show a modal message
      my_data()
      showModal(
        modalDialog(title = 'No data uploaded',
                    'Please upload a file before clicking the button')
      )
    } else {
      # if there is data uploaded, read it and return it
      tmp <- read.csv(input$Upload$datapath)
      my_data(tmp)
    }
  })

  output$showdata = renderDT(my_data(), rownames = FALSE, class = "display nowrap compact", filter = "top",
                             options = list(
                               scrollX = TRUE,
                               scrollY = TRUE,
                               autoWidth = FALSE))

}
```

Checked in my system and working as expected in your question.

### Edit

Edited to offer a more efficient way, avoiding reading everytime the file:

```
# Server Logic
server <- function(input, output) {

  my_data <- reactiveVal()

  ## Not need of this, this will be done when pressing the show data button
  # observeEvent(input$Upload, {
  #   tmp <- read.csv(input$Upload$datapath)
  #   my_data(tmp)
  # })

  # Observer to update my_data when example button is pressed
  observeEvent(input$Example, {
    my_data(recommendation)
  })

  # reactive to store the uploaded data
  data_loaded <- reactive({
    # dont try to read if there is no upload
    shiny::validate(
      shiny::need(input$Upload, 'no data uploaded')
    )
    # read the file
    read.csv(input$Upload$datapath)
  })

  # Observer to update my_data when data button is pressed, checking if there
  # is a file uploaded
  observeEvent(input$data, {

    # check if we have a data uploaded
    if (is.null(input$Upload)) {
      # if there is no data uploaded, reset my_data, and show a modal message
      my_data()
      showModal(
        modalDialog(title = 'No data uploaded',
                    'Please upload a file before clicking the button')
      )
    } else {
      # if there is data uploaded, read it and return it
      tmp <- data_loaded()
      my_data(tmp)
    }
  })

  output$showdata = renderDT(my_data(), rownames = FALSE, class = "display nowrap compact", filter = "top",
                             options = list(
                               scrollX = TRUE,
                               scrollY = TRUE,
                               autoWidth = FALSE))

}
```

Comment: This way is definitely more efficient :). Thanks

Comment: The only issue with this approach is that when you click between the buttons, each time you press 'show new data' it reads the file again and again. Rather than reading it once and just showing the file again is pressed second time.

Comment: That can be solved creating a reactive to load the data (`data_loaded <- reactive({read.csv(input$Upload$datapath)})` and calling in to create tmp in the observeEvent (`tmp <- data_loaded`). This way the data is only readed on data upload change

Comment: Edited answer to offer a more efficient way as per your comment ;)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks you so much :)